# How can I see symbols of (C and C++) binary on linux?

Tags: c++, c, performance, profiling, name-mangling

Which tools do you guys use? How do demangle c++ symbols do be able to pass it to profiler tools, such as [opannotate](http://oprofile.sourceforge.net/doc/opannotate.html)?

Thanks

Answer (score 101, accepted):

Use `nm` to see all symbols and `c++filt` to demangle.

Example:

```
nm -an foo | c++filt
```

Comment: unless the binary was stripped

Comment: In the case of a stripped binary, you can always try gazing into a crystal ball.

Comment: The -C|--demangle[=style] should take care of c++filt's part:
nm -anC foo

Comment: @DanMoulding in case of a stripped binary you can use `readelf -Ws`

Answer (score 0):

The profiling tool I use already knows the symbols and source code, [since it is just the debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/375913/what-can-i-use-to-profile-c-code-in-linux/378024#378024). I can build the app with symbols included, even with full optimization.