# gtest: where to put gdb breakpoint

Tags: gdb, googletest

I am using various xunit tests for years (starting from cppunit in early 2000s). In all cases it was very easy to set a break point on failure: there was a function that indicated detected failure:

b 'atf::tests::tc::fail(std::string const&)'
   command
   up 1
   end

It seems that gtest is quite different, what is the established practice of doing the same with gtest?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> what is the established practice of doing the same with gtest?

Reading `gtest.cc`, the closest I see is `--gunit_break_on_failure`, which should cause the code to execute `INT3` trap on x86/Linux, and to call `DebugBreak` on Windows.

**Update:** the flag appears to have been renamed to `--gtest_break_on_failure` in latest public releases.

Comment: It kinda sorta works - but so far I do not see a way to continue after non-fatal failure and associate debugger commands (e.g. 'up 2'). It will be nice to get something friendlier.

Comment: @zzz777 If you are on "Linux/x86", you can continue from `int3` with GDB `signal 0` command.

Answer (score 4):

If you need to break at the start of the test to observe something, first [get the symbol names present in the executable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1379533/how-can-i-see-symbols-of-c-and-c-binary-on-linux), and grep for the test name of interest, e.g.:

```
nm -C myclass_test | grep MyTest0
```

if you want to break at:

```
TEST(MainTest, MyTest0) {
    EXPECT_EQ(1, 1);
}
```

Of the results of that grep, the most promising one seemed to be:

```
0000000000407c64 T MainTest_MyTest0_Test::TestBody()
```

and so:

```
gdb myclass_test
```

and:

```
b MainTest_MyTest0_Test::TestBody
r
```

and then this leaves me at the start of the desired test.

Tested [with this setup](https://askubuntu.com/questions/97626/how-to-install-googletest/1295185#1295185) at revision 2.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `break test.cpp:42` to break on line 42 of the unit test. That way you don't have to look up the generated symbol names of the tests.